# Java Scanner Validation returning the second input

Tags: java, input, io, java.util.scanner

I have a function here where it verifies the user input if its a number or within bounds.

```
public static int getNumberInput(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(!Inputs.isANumber(input)){
        System.out.println("Negative Numbers and Letters are not allowed");
        input.reset();
    }
    return input.nextInt();
}


public static int getNumberInput(int bound){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int val =   getNumberInput();
    if(val > bound){
        System.out.println("Maximum Input is only up to: "+ bound+" Please Try Again: ");
        input.reset();
        getNumberInput(bound);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Each time I call getNumberInput(int bound) method with this function

```
public void askForDifficulty(){
    System.out.print("Difficulty For This Question:\n1)Easy\n2)Medium\n3)Hard\nChoice: ");
    int choice = Inputs.getNumberInput(diff.length);
    System.out.println(choice);
}
```

if I inserted an out of bound number lets say the only maximum number is 5. the getNumberInput(int bound) will call itself again. and when I insert the correct or within bound value it will only return to me the first value/previous value I inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` in the `getNumberInput(int bound)` should be a `while`. **EDIT** You should also combine the two methods:

```
public static int getNumberInput(int bound){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (;;) {
        if (!Inputs.isANumber(input)) {
            System.out.println("Negative Numbers and Letters are not allowed");
            input.reset();
            continue;
        }
        int val = getNumberInput();
        if (val <= bound) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum Input is only up to: "+ bound+" Please Try Again: ");
        input.reset();
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: It is working but the input is being read only after I input it 2 times.

Comment: What does reset do? is reset really needed?

Comment: @user962206 I copied the `reset()` call from your code. If you do not think it is necessary, feel free to remove it.